# doctrine:generate:crud for Entites outside a bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, namespaces, crud

When I try to create a doctrine crud for an entity I get an 'Unknown entity namespace alias' exception.

[image]

I have the following project structure

[image]

With a series of bundles (in the Bundles directory) using the Entities in the src\Project\Entity directory.

As you can see my entity namespace is

```
    namespace Project\Entity;
```

[image]

I have a feeling it might be to do with the auto_mapping, but I have been playing with this for 4-5 hours and am getting nowhere.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

Create a command which extends the base doctrine crud command

extends \Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineCrudCommand

Modifying

```
 $entityClass = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getAliasNamespace('Project').'\\'.$entity;
```

to the namespace of the entity. By default it assumes the entity is in the Bundle where you want the CRUD to be created.

By setting

```
$this->setName('project:generate:crud');
```

in the Configre() function you can call the function from your command line

Example:

```
<?php

namespace Project\Bundle\UtilityBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion;
use Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\Validators;

class GenerateDoctrineCrudCommand extends \Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineCrudCommand
{
protected function configure()
{
    parent::configure();

    $this->setName('project:generate:crud');
    $this->setDescription('CRUD generator that supports entities outside a bundle');
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $questionHelper = $this->getQuestionHelper();

    if ($input->isInteractive()) {
        $question = new ConfirmationQuestion($questionHelper->getQuestion('Do you confirm generation', 'yes', '?'), true);
        if (!$questionHelper->ask($input, $output, $question)) {
            $output->writeln('<error>Command aborted</error>');

            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Note: this expects an argument like InterpracCorporateFrontendBundle:Notification
    list($bundle, $entity) = explode(':', $input->getOption('entity'));

    $format = Validators::validateFormat($input->getOption('format'));
    $prefix = $this->getRoutePrefix($input, $entity);
    $withWrite = $input->getOption('with-write');
    $forceOverwrite = $input->getOption('overwrite');

    $questionHelper->writeSection($output, 'CRUD generation');

    $entityClass = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getAliasNamespace('Project').'\\'.$entity;
    $metadata    = $this->getEntityMetadata($entityClass);
    $bundle      = $this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getBundle($bundle);

    $generator = $this->getGenerator($bundle);
    $generator->generate($bundle, $entity, $metadata[0], $format, $prefix, $withWrite, $forceOverwrite);

    $output->writeln('Generating the CRUD code: <info>OK</info>');

    $errors = array();
    $runner = $questionHelper->getRunner($output, $errors);

    // form
    if ($withWrite) {
        $output->write('Generating the Form code: ');
        if ($this->generateForm($bundle, $entity, $metadata)) {
            $output->writeln('<info>OK</info>');
        } else {
            $output->writeln('<warning>Already exists, skipping</warning>');
        }
    }

    // routing
    if ('annotation' != $format) {
        $runner($this->updateRouting($questionHelper, $input, $output, $bundle, $format, $entity, $prefix));
    }

    $questionHelper->writeGeneratorSummary($output, $errors);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are keeping your entities outside bundles. Since this is not standard behaviour, you have to extend or create another `GenerateDoctrineCrudCommand` to be able to pass namespace alias.

Comment: I don't have time atm to look thought the code, I will update the answer tonight